# Phonegap based web application generated by GWT comiler doesn't run on xcode simulator

Tags: gwt, cordova, ios-simulator, mgwt

I'm using GWT to create the UI for my Mobile application and move the compiled code to a phonegap application.
Every thing works fine in Android simulator (and Galaxy S2). But when trying to create an iphone application, I got a blank page without any worning or error.

I'm stuck in this problem even though I followed all the instructions in the getting started tutorial http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS. Have you please any idea?

GWT version: 2.4,
JDK: 1.6,
Phonegap cordova: 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.m-gwt.com

It has a library for building gwt applications for phonegap. The bootup situation (which can be quite tricky) is handled inside gwt-phonegap

Comment: Do I have to make changes to my GWT application to use the jar? If yes, what are the changes in the .gwt.xml that I have to do?

Comment: take a look at the wiki "Getting Started": http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm not on Mac now so I'll that tomorrow and I'll tell you the result. Thanks

Comment: You are awesome Daniel! Thanks for sharing this project!